# How to terminate Scanf() if input entered after whitespace is invalid one in C?

Tags: c

Suppose I have to enter 3 inputs separated by space.
Let it be "3 4 5".
now if user inputs "3 10 5" and as only single digit is accepted as a constraint

I want to make scanf() terminate after 10 when space is entered.

Please help.

Comment: `scanf()` is not for *reading* input, it's for *parsing* input (from [my doc for beginners](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)) -- so you *probably* won't use `scanf()` for this job. But first clarify whether you want to avoid the actual *typing* of the user or you only want to stop parsing (the latter *could* be done with `scanf()`, but there are better methods)

Comment: You might want to investigate `getc()`.

Comment: You have a couple of options.  One is to accept that people won't do what you want and check that you got three values and check that they're in range. Another is to specify `%1d`, but that means the input will be treated as 3, 1, 0 because `scanf()` doesn't insist on spaces before the input. In context, checking afterwards is probably best.  You might need to do line-based input (`fgets()` etc) and string scanning (`sscanf()`).

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `fget()` to read a *line* of user input.

---

> ... to make scanf() terminate after 10 when space entered ...

`scanf()` is not the best tool in the shed for this task.

By *space*, I assume OP will tolerate *white-spaces* which includes space, tab. line-feed, and others.

Remember that `stdin` is usually line buffered, but to stop `scanf()` after an invalid number (more than 1 digit), code needs to limit or keep track of the number of characters entered.  " 10" will fail, "00 " will fail, " +1" will fail, "  7 " will pass.

```
// read 1 `int` at a time.
// Use %n to record the offset of the scan up to that point
int left, right, n;

//               +--==------ consume white-spaces
//               | +-------- Record offset
//               | | +------ Record `int`
//               | | | +---- Record offset
int cnt = scanf(" %n%d%n", &left, &n, &right);
if (cnt == 1 && right == left + 1) {
  Success();
} else {
  Fail();
}
```

Other `scanf()` approaches may begin with  `" %1[0-9]%c"` (test if 2nd is a space) or `" %1d%c"`.

Answer (score 0):

use getchar() to check if their remains any extra junk other than a single digit and if exists terminate

```
int main() {
    int a=0,b=0,c=0;
    char s;

    scanf("%1d",&a);
    if((s = getchar()) != ' ')
        return 0;

    scanf("%1d",&b);
    if((s = getchar()) != ' ')
        return 0;


    scanf("%1d",&c);
    if((s=getchar()) !='\n')
        return 0;


    printf("\na %d",a);
    printf("\nb %d ",b);
    printf("\nc %d ",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommend to also check the return value of `scanf()` to see if it is the expected 1.

Comment: yes a good optimization ...but if the user is restricted to certain constraints it can be eliminated